# Correct use of generator to plot multiple lines with plotly

Tags: python, plotly, generator

I am learning plotly and python so I lack some theory on that.
I tried to run this code, the main scope is to use the same value twice for the x parameter and then iterate through all the values inside `high_peaks_dates` to trace vertical lines, tried many iterations with and without the `*` but none seem to work.

```
...
figure.add_trace(
    go.Scatter(
        x=[(high_peaks_dates[j], high_peaks_dates[j]) for j in range(len(high_peaks_dates))],
        y=[df.High.max(), df.High.min()],
        mode='lines',
        name='lines'
    )
)
...
```

I also tried putting the for loop outside, but it comes with many downsides: slower loading and most importantly different 'labels' for each line in the legend. The method `add_vline()` doesn't fit my program unfortunately.
Was the use of the generator wrong? Can it be used in these scenarios? If not, which could be a good alternative? Thank you in advance

Edit:
x is a tuple of the x coordinates for the line I want to plot, so my plan is to use the same value of `high_peaks_dates` list twice so it traces a vertical line and then proceeds to the next value in the list.

This is a sample of the `high_peaks_list` list. Timestamp is because it comes from a pandas Timestamp

```
[Timestamp('2006-01-12 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2007-07-27 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2007-12-27 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2008-05-14 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2010-04-26 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2010-06-21 00:00:00'), ...
```

and this is a sample of the df pandas Dataframe, printed with the `.head()` method

```
                Open      High       Low     Close  Adj Close     Volume
Date                                                                    
2000-01-03  0.936384  1.004464  0.907924  0.999442   0.849468  535796800
2000-01-04  0.966518  0.987723  0.903460  0.915179   0.777850  512377600
...
```

The plotly plot uses the same pandas Timestamp as x-axis so it works with the `df.Date` format

The Dataframe's Date column is also the index.

Comment: it's a little hard to tell what you're trying to do... it looks like x is a list of tuples but they don't change for iterations of the loop? if you're trying to use a loop to plot a bunch of traces, i think you decrease the burden on the renderer by not having a legend entry for every one of those traces. if you could provide samples of `high_peaks_dates.head().to_dict()` and do the same for `df`, that would be helpful so we can try to reproduce the issue you're having

Comment: I agree with Derek O. What happens if you take out the parentheses (   )  from the X assignment? And replace the 50 by j as iterable. Also: the shape of df is unclear, so I'm not sure if Y is assigned properly. That's not being iterated over.

Comment: Thank you, i was testing with arbitrary values and so I posted that version by mistake. j was the correct index there inside the loop. If i take the parentheses out it still doesn't work. I used the Y values to get a vertical line that somewhat fills the vertical space of the graph and from my testings it works but can work better.
`go.Scatter` is `plotly.graph_object.Scatter`. Let me know if some more context is needed.